# Retrieving single data from a column

Tags: c#, sql

I am creating a web form and I have 5 textbox. The data that will be put here will come from a Stored Proc which returns a table with 2 columns like this:

```
----------------
| ID  | Amount |
|1    | 5      |
|2    | 9      |
|3    | 2      |
|4    | 1      |
|5    | 57     |
----------------
```

Now, how can I assign in an efficient way the specific value to its corresponding textbox which depends on the ID column like this:

```
    if ID="1" then txt_ID1.Text = "5";
    ...txt_ID2.Text = "9";
    ...txt_ID3.Text = "2";
    ...txt_ID4.Text = "1";
    ...txt_ID5.Text = "57";
```

Answer (score 1):

Let `dtResult` be the DataTable that you were populated with the stored procedure, Since DataTable follows `0` based indexing and it allows you to get the rows based on the index, you can use the following code to get values to the textBoxes.

```
 if (dtResult.Rows.Count >= 4)
 {
     txt_ID1.Text = dtResult.Rows[0]["Amount"].ToString();
     txt_ID2.Text = dtResult.Rows[1]["Amount"].ToString();
     txt_ID3.Text = dtResult.Rows[2]["Amount"].ToString();
     txt_ID4.Text = dtResult.Rows[3]["Amount"].ToString();
     txt_ID5.Text = dtResult.Rows[4]["Amount"].ToString();
 }
```

Comment: Or have an array of controls and look through the rows. `txt_ID[n].Text=dtResult.Rows[n]["Amount"].ToString();`

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add that I  need the retrieving to be conditional. like the value depends on the ID column. because the order of the retrieving might change. I want it to be like 
if ID="1" then txt_ID1="5"

Comment: @LoztInSpace: Yep, there are possibilities for that, but its fine to use like my suggestion if the number of textboxes are less, we shall go for iteration if they are more

Comment: @theo: could you please be more clear about the requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You can find your controls in server side code and assign your value to Text property, I supposed your stored procedure **result** is in a **`dictionary`**, But you can do it in your way, So my recommended code is something like this:

```
Dictionary<int, object> spResult = new Dictionary<int, object>();
spResult.ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            var control = Controls.Cast<Control>().FirstOrDefault(y => y.ID == string.Format("txt_ID{0}", x.Key)) as TextBox;
            if (control != null)
                control.Text = x.Value.ToString();
        });
    }
```

Comment: This is a great approach. But I am new to C#, I don't know how to plot this. Can you help me? my SQLCommand is "EXEC [dbo].[GetAmount]"

Comment: I will send you full code here

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
            DataTable dataTable=new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(*<YourConnectionString>*))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAmount", connection))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
                        {
                            var control=Controls.Cast<Control>().FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID==string.Format("txt_ID{0}",dr["ID"])) as TextBox;
                            if (control != null)
                                control.Text = dr["Amount"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for this but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why? What is the problem?

Comment: I have no idea, there is no error returned :(

Comment: :| So how may I know what is the problem !??!!